# Ubuntu LXC 14.04 Error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, lxc

I had installed LXC in ubuntu 14.04. I had used an existing template and created a VM by executing the below command.

`/usr/share/lxc-templates/lxc-ubuntu -p /lxc/vm0`

After the installation getting the below error.

`lxc-unshare: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxc.so.1: undefined symbol: cgmanager_get_pid_cgroup_abs_sync`

The same error get repeated whever i execute any command with `lxc-*`.

- What can be the problem?
- How can i get this fixed?

Thanks

Sandeep Krishnan

Comment: Hi Guys,
apt-get upgrade fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because you are running an old libcgmanager. To fix this problem, you need to update libcgmanager.
`$ sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0 --upgrade`

Comment: This solution is better than the best answer. That one upgrades all the packages which it is not desired all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here:

https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/247

You basically just need to update your ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it should work.